# Is Mark 6:3 an allusion to Proverbs 8:30?

Tags: mark, proverbs, intertextuality

> New American Standard Bible Mark 6:3  "**Is not this the carpenter**, the son
>   of Mary, and brother of James and Joses and Judas and Simon? Are not
>   His sisters here with us?" And they took offense at Him.
>
> New American Standard Bible Proverbs 8:30  Then I was beside Him, **as a master
>   workman**; And I was daily His delight, Rejoicing always before Him,

See related post:  [Is Mark 6:3 an allusion to Wisdom of Solomon 7:22?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/30100/is-mark-63-an-allusion-to-wisdom-of-solomon-722)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's highly doubtful.

On the Greek side of things, the wording isn't the same. Jesus is identified in Mark 6.3 as a τέκτων ('[worker in wood](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=%CF%84%E1%BD%B3%CE%BA%CF%84%CF%89%CE%BD&la=greek)'). LXX Proverbs 8.30 translates the Hebrew loosely, with Lady Wisdom saying ἤμην παρ’ αὐτῷ ἁρμόζουσα ἐγὼ ἤμην ('I was beside him, fitting together [creation]').

Those speaking this in Mark 6.3 are people from Galilee who are surprised by Jesus. The other Synoptics modify the crowd's question. Matthew 13.55 changes the wording to 'Isn't this the carpenter's son?', while Luke 4.22 has 'Isn't this Joseph's son?' The question is rhetorical, they know his family and their profession. The question's intention is to draw attention to Jesus' apparent lack of qualifications to be teaching in the synagogue.

The crowd wouldn't be identifying Jesus as the embodiment of Lady Wisdom, the personification of God's wisdom. The reference to wisdom in the previous verse is incidental to this point; in fact, the context has them question his wisdom. Camille Focant, *The Gospel According to Mark*, 224:

> Marcus* (378) wrongly considers that the second series of questions could easily be taken in a positive sense: "This kid has grown up right here in Nazareth, under our very noses, in a family we all knew—and we never guessed what fantastic things he was capable of!" Indeed, it is a more believable matter to take Jesus back "to the common social level," so especially since the reader already knows the hostility of the familial group to Jesus' action (3:21, 31-35) (Barnouin, 473).

In other words, the crowd is incredulous that Jesus could be a wise teacher, since he was merely a carpenter from a local family. Hence:

> And they took offense at him. Then Jesus said to them, 'Prophets are not without honor, except in their home town, and among their own king,
>  and in their own house.'